# Handlebars JS on Array of Hashes

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, handlebars.js

I am new to Handlebars JS and just trying to understand them. 
I am trying to implement handlebars on a data that contains array of hashes.
Here is my script:-

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{body}}</h2>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function (){

     var source = $("#template").html();
     var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

     var context  = [{title: "ABC",body: "DEF"},{title: "GHI",body:"JKL"}];

     console.log(context);
     var ht = template(context);
     console.log(ht);
     $("#test").html(ht);
 });

</script>
```

Nothing is displayed on the output
How to use the handlebars template to access an array of hashes. Ex- variable `context` in the above script. 
Can we use handlebars only on hashes ?

Can anyone please explain me this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through collection using {{#each}} helper. In your case it would be something like this:

```
{{#each this}}
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>{{body}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

Of course we can use it only on hashes - just try.
You might find reading this useful: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

I hope your script tag doesn't look like in your post and it actually doesn't lack of "http" part

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can I use the same template for Mustache ? {{#each this}} is not supported in mustache

Comment: If you could show me your code it would be easier for me to answer. I've never used mustache but I think there must be a way to pass a collection's name. If your context variable was: var context  = {fancyName: [{title: "ABC",body: "DEF"},{title: "GHI",body:"JKL"}]}; then you should write {{#each fancyName}}. If it didn't help paste your code.